# Setup project slow to install Windows service and client

Tags: deployment, windows-services, installation, windows-installer, compatibility

I am currently using the Visual Studio 2010 Setup Project to deploy my application to an MSI installer file, which includes a Windows Service and a Windows Forms application. But I am disappointed with the performance and compatibility of this form of packaging.

My application is compatible with Windows XP and upwards, but several older XP user-testing boxes simply don't have the right version of the Windows Installer or the necessary service pack installed. (Un)installation can take dreadfully long for a program under 1MB in size and many systems do not support it. `InstallState` errors can crop up and ruin the (un)installation if the service has been deleted or already installed, or if any program files are missing (for uninstall).

### What I need from an (un)installer:

1. Manage .NET dependencies.
2. Copy/remove my application files to a folder.
3. Add/remove menu and shortcuts to the desktop and Start menu.
4. (Un)install a Windows service, though I can also do this from my application. The stop and uninstall part is important.
5. Run my application when it's done.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767/what-is-the-best-choice-for-building-windows-installers)'s answers recommend NSIS (which I have used with good results) and WiX. Ironically there is no easy link to simple installer for WiX on their website.

Am I missing something with VS2010's setup project? It is optimized for speed, but it's just too slow.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the installer/uninstaller explicitly with

```
msiexec /x thefile.msi /l*v thefile.log
```

(/i for install). Then inspect the log file; it will have time stamps telling you what action took what amount of time. Of course, the logging will affect that, but you should get an idea what makes it take so long.